# use jmeter to load test a site: the url is different every time while running the script

Tags: jmeter

I try to test a site with Jmeter and I used its HTTP Proxy sever to make the script.

Actually, the process of this script is 

1. login

2. click a link to another page and fill in some info and **click SUBMIT**

3. logout.

The problem is: everytime I run the script, everything is going well before hitting the SUBMIT button. 'cuz after hitting it, 8 random numbers or letters will be added to the url. So, everytime i run the script, the url is different from the first time that made the script.

Is there anyone has run into kind of question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things to consider:

1. Are these "random numbers" in the source code, or just the URL as a
   parameter? If so, see below.
2. Are they a JSESSION ID?  If so - use a cookie manager. 
   That should solve the issue.

If they are in the source code, you'll need to use a regular expression to extract the value.  You'll want it as a child of Step2, making your structure:

```
Login
Form Page
 --- Regex for Submit button
Submit
```

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Comment: the problem has been solved. I get the 8 numbers/letters from the response in the page before the submit page, and make it as a variable and add it into the submit page's url, and problem solved!Thank u for helpin' me !